# Please take a stab at this VB.Net Oracle-related sample and help me with String.Format

Tags: vb.net, oracle, stored-procedures, string-formatting

If the database is not Oracle, it is MS SQl 2008.
My task: if Oracle, add two more parameters when calling a stored proc.

Oracle and MSFT stored procs are generated; Oracle ones have 3 extra parameters:

```
Vret_val out number,
Vparam2 in out number,
Vparam3 in out number,
... the rest
```

(The are not actually named Vparam2 and Vparam3, but this should not matter).
So, the code for a helper VB.Net class that calls a stored proc:

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Configuration

Dim objCon As OdbcConnection = Nothing
Dim objAdapter As OdbcDataAdapter
Dim cmdCommand As New OdbcCommand
Dim objDataTable As DataTable

Dim sconnection As String

Try
    sconnection = mConnectionString
    objAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter
    objCon = New OdbcConnection(sconnection)
    objCon.Open()

    objAdapter.SelectCommand = cmdCommand
    objAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = objCon
    objAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    objAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = Globals.mReportTimeOut

    If Not mIsOracle Then
        objAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = String.Format("{{call {0}}}", spName)
    Else
        Dim returnValue As New OdbcParameter
        returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        returnValue.ParameterName = "@Vret_val"
        returnValue.OdbcType = OdbcType.Numeric
        objAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(returnValue)

        objAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = String.Format("{{call {0}(?)}}", spName)
    End If

    Try

        objDataTable = New DataTable(spName)
        objAdapter.Fill(objDataTable)

    Catch ex As Exception
    ...
```

Question: I am puzzled as to what `String.Format("{{call {0}(?)}}", spName)` does, in particular the `(?)` part. My understanding of the String.Format is that it will simply replace {0} with spName. The `{{`, `}}`, and `(?)` do throw me off because `{` reminds me of formatting, `(?)` hints at some advanced regex use.

Unfortunately I am getting little help from a key person who is on vacation without a <strike>leash</strike> [smart]phone.

I am guessing that I simply add 5 more lines for each additional parameter, and change `String.Format("{{call {0}(?)}}", spName)` to `String.Format("{{call {0}(?,?,?)}}", spName)`. I forgot to mention that I am coding this "blindly" - I have a compiler to help me, but no environment set up to test this.

This will be over in a few days, but I need to do my best to try finishing it on time :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.Format("{{call {0}(?)}}", spName)` will produce a string like this: `"{call ProcName(?)}"` (assuming `spName` contains the string `ProcName`). `{{` and ´}}`are needed if you want the to include`{`or`}` in the string without them being part of the formatting.

This is mentioned in the documentation for [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx):

> The leading and trailing brace
>   characters, '{' and '}', are required.
>   To specify a single literal brace
>   character in format, specify two
>   leading or trailing brace characters;
>   that is, "{{" or "}}".

The `(?)` means nothing special for the `string.Format` function, but will be used when executing the given procedure, each question mark representing a parameter that should be passed to the procedure.

Comment: Thanks ... but what happens to the `(?)` ?

Comment: Thanks again ... now, about meaning of `(?)` - was that a guess. I have to add 2 more, so should it be `(???)`, `(?,?,?)`, `(?)(?)(?)`, `(?),(?),(?)`, or something else? This follow-up question is open to everyone.

Comment: Without having tested it, I would guess the second option: `(?,?,?)`.